# Android - update a file in res/raw folder

Tags: android

I want to update the content of a file on my res/raw folder called dbschema.xml, using a newer version of dbschema.xml that is somewhere on the phone (for exemple, at data/data//dbschema.xml)
I've already done the part to check if the new file exists, and i want now to copy it to raw.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, you can't modify the content of those files since they are inside the installation package. You could instead copy the file to the private directory of your app, read it from there and update when needed.